# I am trying to use Intel realsense D415 cameras to do gmapping, and the graph is getting formed but in a specific wedge only

Tags: ros, navigation, realsense-camera, gmapping, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did depthscan_to_laserscan but there were a lot of nan values under the /scan topic. Could that be the reason for the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296286/i-am-trying-to-use-intel-realsense-d415-cameras-to-do-gmapping,-and-the-graph-is-getting-formed-but-in-a-specific-wedge-only-even-if-i-rotate-the-sensor-in-all-angles./) by [srnand](https://answers.ros.org/users/34391/srnand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2018-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think It is because, the Fixed Frame in rviz in not moving. So I have change the Fixed frame. Let me know if this is not the correct solution.

---

Originally posted by [srnand](https://answers.ros.org/users/34391/srnand/) with karma: 31 on 2018-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0